# IE11 ignores aria-checked state

Tags: internet-explorer, radio-button, internet-explorer-11, wai-aria

I'm using a `button` with `role="radio"` like this:

`<button role="radio" aria-checked="true" aria-label="Yes">`

but the AccExplorer32 doesnt show this as "checked" or "selected", JAWS17 reads it always as "Yes radio button not checked"

In Chrome VOX it reads nicely, just IE11 has a problem. Do you know how to force the state to be noticed without changing `button` into `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug filed describing this problem, but Microsoft has closed it, partly because they did not reproduce it and partly because resources are focused on Edge now.

> IE11 does not pick up ARIA checked state for radio roles
>
> …
>
> Have you tried using these technologies in Microsoft Edge? Do you also see the same bugs or issues using that browser? Do note that at the moment we are not actively working on feature bugs for Internet Explorer unless they are security related.

Bug report is at https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1157686/ie11-does-not-pick-up-aria-checked-state-for-radio-roles